# How to merge elements of a list of strings based on conditional

Tags: python

Say that I have a string list like this

`stringlist = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'str', '##ing', 'list', 'for', 'ex', '##ample', 'for']`

I want to merge the elements that start before and on the element that start with '##' and also remove the '##'.

So 'str' and '##ing' would be merged to 'string', and 'ex' and '##ample' would be merged to 'example'.

So this would be the desired result

`['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'list', 'for', 'example', 'for']`

I wrote a for loop to solve this

```
new = []
for idx, ele in enumerate(stringlist):
    if ele.startswith('##'):
        new[-1] = new[-1] + ele[2:]
    else:
        new.append(ele)
```

Is there a more computationally efficient or programatically elegant way to get this results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution that iterates through the list in pairs, and skips a pair if the last item added to the list was a string formed from joining a pair. I don't know that it will be more efficient than your existing solution, but the nice thing about it is that it doesn't involve having to modify items already added to the new list.

```
def merge(stringlist):
    new = []
    skip = False
     
    for first, second in zip(stringlist, (stringlist[1:] + ['#'])):
        if skip:
            skip = False
        elif second.startswith('#'):
            new.append(f'{first}{second.lstrip("#")}')
            skip = True
        else:
            new.append(first)

    return new
```

`['#']` has to be added to `stringlist[1:]` in order to compensate for the fact that `zip` terminates as soon as the shortest iterable is exhausted. Note that you could also use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Output:

```
>>> merge(['this', 'is', 'a', 'str', '##ing', 'list', 'for', 'ex', '##ample', 'for', '##a'])
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'list', 'for', 'example', 'fora']
>>> merge(['this', 'is', 'a', 'str', '##ing', 'list', 'for', 'ex', '##ample', 'for'])
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'list', 'for', 'example', 'for']
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if computationally better but in an elegant way you can use `remove()` function and `join()` function for deleting the item and merging with the previous one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).